# How to extends a facade in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm try extends a facede in laravel 4, but I only get a next error on try calling a method.

```
Non-static method App\Libraries\Theme::setActive() should not be called statically
```

### Edit

After responce of @Antonio, to change the method to static, let the power of using the keyword $ this-> inside the method.

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException Using
$this when not in object context in `$active = $this->ensureRegistered($active);`

My code:

```
<?php namespace App\Libraries;

use Cartalyst\Themes\Facades\Theme as ThemeBag;

class Theme extends ThemeBag {

    /**
     * Sets the active theme.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $active
     * @return Cartalyst\Themes\ThemeInterface
     */
public static function setActive($active)
{
    $active = $this->ensureRegistered($active);

    if ( ! isset($this->themes[$active->getSlug()]))
    {
        $this->register($active);
    }

    $this->active = $active;

    include $this->getActive()->getPath() . '\\helpers\\composers.php';
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Basically you'll have to extend an existing Facade:

```
<?php namespace AntonioRibeiro\Libraries;

class MyEventFacade extends Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event {

    /**
     * Sets the active theme.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $active
     * @return Cartalyst\Themes\ThemeInterface
     */
    public static function setActive($active)
    {
        /// do what you have to do
    }

}
```

And then replace (or add it as a new one) to your app/config/app.php:

```
'aliases' => array(

        'App'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',
                ...
     // 'Event'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event',
        'Event'      => 'AntonioRibeiro\Libraries\MyEventFacade',
                ...
        'File'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\File',
        'ActiveSession'   => 'AntonioRibeiro\Facades\ActiveSessionFacade',

),
```

Don't forget do execute 'composer dump-autoload'.

I don't have access to those Cartalyst Themes, but the error you where receiving was related to the method you didn't created as static:

```
public function setActive($active)
{
}
```

Shoud be

```
public static function setActive($active)
{
}
```

You'll find some good information about it here (make a class extending the Request "Facade"): http://fideloper.com/extend-request-response-laravel

Comment: You should summarize the main points @Antonio and then reference the article.

Comment: thx for you response. to change the method to static, let the power of using the keyword $this inside the method.