# Laravel: Cannot access protected function of Facade

Tags: php, laravel

I want to rewrite `onceBasic()` of `Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard` by extending `Facades\Auth`, but encountering the problem of not being able to access the helper protected function of `SessionGuard` class.
Here is how I extends Auth facades:

```
namespace App\MyFacades;
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Auth_QuyLe extends Auth {

        /**
         * Create your custom methods here...
         */
        public static function onceBasic_QuyLe($field = 'name', $extraConditions = [])
        {   
            $credentials =  self::basicCredentials(self::getRequest(), $field);

            if (! self::once(array_merge($credentials, $extraConditions))) {
                return self::failedBasicResponse();
            }
        }

}
```

When I call `onceBasic_QuyLe()` from my middleware, it shows

```
"Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::basicCredentials does not exist."
```

I've already updated my class to config/app.php and run `composer dump-autoload && php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Don't try to make any changes to a Facade. Facades simply resolve an instance of the underlying class which in this case is the currently used Auth guard (SessionGuard).

Comment: No... I don't changes Facades... I don't modify a single code of laraval core... What I did is to "extend it", creating my own function, utilizing some helpers from Auth Facades... 
Here are some similar posts in SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40614875/laravel-5-extend-a-facade |
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953460/how-to-extends-a-facade-in-laravel |
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52944843/extending-db-facade-laravel
I am not sure why in my situation, I just can't access the protected function of Auth facades, although public function is fine...

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't trying to suggest you were editing anything in the core. What I meant was extending the Facade itself isn't the answer. For the most part think of a Facade like a helper function e.g. `auth()->user()` and `Auth::user()` will call the same method because they're actually delegating the call to the underlying `Guard` class. Realistically, you need to extend the underlying `Guard` class and have Laravel use that instead.

Comment: Anyway, what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: OK...Thanks for your suggestion... I just tried out extending the underlying Guard class: 
`<?php 

class Auth_QuyLe extends SessionGuard {
... 
}` but it still shows the same error `"Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::onceBasic_QuyLe does not exist"`, which means they cannot access the extended function (`onceBasic_QuyLe()` ) that I've just added.
I'm using Laravel 5.8

Comment: https://gist.github.com/wayanjimmy/afa85e211e2cdd6bacf5daa849bac749

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a solution:

Firstly, b/c `SessionGuard` is a “macroable” class, and if you need to add an additional method to `SessionGuard` , you need to go to `AppServiceProvider` and declare macros into the service provider’s boot method

```
public function boot()
    {
        SessionGuard::macro('myOnceBasic', function ($field = 'name', $extraConditions = []) {

            $credentials = $this->basicCredentials($this->getRequest(), $field);

            if (!$this->once(array_merge($credentials, $extraConditions))) {
                return$this->failedBasicResponse();
            }
        });
}
```

and in the underlying class that your newly created Facades represents , you can use Auth facade to call the macros:

```
class MySessionGuard{

        public function myOnceBasic($field = 'name', $extraConditions = [])
        {   
            Auth::myOnceBasic($field = 'name', $extraConditions = []);
        }

}
```